# Как написать свою библиотеку визуализации графа?

Tags: c++, визуализация

Здравствуйте. Группа студентов получила задание реализовать несколько алгоритмов на графах. Работаем в Visual Studio, язык с++.

Я же получил задание реализовать пошаговую визуализацию этих алгоритмов, при этом, у программы должен быть графический интерфейс.

Преподаватель попросил, чтобы я реализовал библиотеку, которую другие пользователи подключали бы к своим проектам и вызывали функции перерисовки графа в нужный момент времени.

Т.е. у них есть определенная структура данных, отвечающая за представление графа, у них есть моя библиотека, они создают консольное приложение, добавляют туда мою библиотеку и при запуске у них вместе с консолью появляется окно визуализации.
При реализации алгоритма, они вызывают функции перерисовки графа и в моем окне граф должен отрисоваться заново.

Вопрос, возможно ли это реализовать? Если да, с помощью каких технологий? литература?

Comment: Их там полно уже готовых, но наиболее прилично выглядит очевидно [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). Если хотите пострадать самому, пытаясь конвертировать матрицы смежности или списки ребер в картинки можно воспользоваться [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) в качестве рисовалки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеку Qt и класс `QGraphicsScene` - 
[пример](http://zenden.ws/ru/graph)

Comment: ссылка не рабочая